# iPhone - reading .epub files

Tags: iphone, unzip, epub

I am engaged in preparing an application regarding reading the .epub files in iPhone. Where can I get the reference for sample applications for unzipping and parsing the files? Can anyone guide me with a best link? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of Ole's answer (that's a pretty good how-to guide), it's definitely worth reading the specification for the [Open Container Format (OCF)](http://www.idpf.org/doc_library/epub/OCF_2.0.1_draft.doc) - sorry it's a word file. It's the formal specification for the for zip structure used.

In brief you parse the file by

1. Checking it's plausibly valid by looking for the text 'mimetype' starting at byte 30 and the text 'application/epub+zip' starting at byte 38.
2. Extracting the file META-INF/container.xml from the zip
3. Parsing that file and extracting the value of the `full-path` attribute of the first `rootfile` element in it.
4. Load the referenced file (the `full-path` attribute is a URL relative to the root of zip file)
5. Parse that file. It contains all the metadata required to reference all the other content (mostly XHTML/CSS/images). Particularly you want to read the contents of the `spine` element which will list all content files in reading order.

If you want to do it right, you should probably also handle [DTBook](http://www.daisy.org/daisy-standard) content as well.

If you want to do this right, you need to read and understand the [Open Packaging Format (OPF)](http://www.idpf.org/doc_library/epub/OPF_2.0.1_draft.htm) and [Open Publication Structure (OPS)](http://www.idpf.org/doc_library/epub/OPS_2.0.1_draft.htm) specifications as well.

Comment: Not as far as I know - most of the companies that I deal with have licensed either Adobe's SDK for this or (I think) embedding Stanza. Sorry - I work with EPUBs themselves not with reading systems.

Comment: I've just been reminded that there is the [FBReader](http://www.fbreader.org/about.php) open source project.

Answer (score 2):

An .epub file is just a .zip file. It contains a few directory files in XML format and the actual book content is usually XHTML. You can use [Objective-Zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/) to unzip the .epub file and then use `NSXMLParser` to parse the XML files.

More info: [Epub Format Construction Guide](http://www.hxa.name/articles/content/epub-guide_hxa7241_2007.html)